# FPS drops when "requesting twitch.tv streams update"

Tags: team-fortress-2

My FPS is usually 100-120

Consistently when it says "Requesting twitch.tv streams update..." in the console, my FPS drops to 10-15 for around 10 seconds.

I can't find any setting or command to disable it, and can't find anyone else having (had) the issue.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Find the file `mainmenuoverride.res` and delete `WatchStreamButton` and `StreamListPanel`. This should disable the streams and the requests.